# Android App/Website for learning vocabulary + deleting vocabulary I already know from list

Tags: android

So I know Cram and Quizlet which I sometimes use for learning short lists of vocabulary for tests (less than 100 words). Now, I want to learn English for my Cambridge C2 exam and for my final exams in school where I need to learn much more than these 100 words, also for life-long learning I have lists with over 1000 words.

All Apps I know don't have the option to delete vocabulary out of the list if I know it e.g. five times in a row. That would be my first criteria for such a vocabulary trainer.

I'm also looking for a trainer where I can upload the vocabulary from an excel spreadsheet (as already said more than 1000 words, don't want to type them in by hand).

The third one (which is less important) is that sometimes it also tests vocabulary I already know, if I still know it - ok, if I don't know it it goes back to the studying-list.

Now, I could program that for myself but I don't have time so I'm looking for some already existing software which includes at least the first two criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't delete vocabulary from your list once you know it, because eventually you'll probably forget it. Instead use a [spaced repetition system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition), where it will only ask you things you know after increasing time spans, like 1 day, 3 days, 1 week, 1 month, 5 months, 2 years, 10 years. But if at any time you forget, then the cycle begins again, and it will ask you the term more frequently until you can show you remember it.

One of the best spaced repetition apps is [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/), which does have an Android app, but also lets you sync your database between your phone, your desktop, or their web app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out My Word List for Android. You can save your words in a list, and delete the ones you don't need. You can import your own list of words into it.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortylove.mywordlist.free

```
Some key features:
•   Offline dictionary with over 800,000 terms.
•   Offline example sentences.
•   Study lists included:  GRE, SAT, ACT, TOEFL, GMAT, IELTS, LSAT, MCAT, PRAXIS, TOEIC. 
•   Shows word frequency (“popularity or ranking”).
•   Add any words, terms or sentences to your list, including ones not in the dictionary.
•   4 Learning levels:  New (1), Learning (2), Advanced (3) and Mastered (4). Each level has different colors. Update your level as you go.
•   Word Finder tool allows you to locate your personal words in articles. 
•   Links to Google Definition, Translate, Google Image and Videos, Webster dictionary (online)
•   Listen to the word’s pronunciation in UK and US accents.
•   Search the dictionary or your personal word lists. using partial word searches, custom filters and sort orders. Sort by frequency, or alphabetical order. learning status, or the last day you viewed, modified, or added the words.
•   Wildcard search available, search for words with certain letters, with patterns such as * and ?.
•   Create your own groups or custom lists. Each word can belong to multiple groups.
•   Lookup definitions from any app. 
•   Import your own word lists into the application. Backup and save your data to a text file. Import the same data later if you need to.
•   Automatic backup/restore in your google account. If you reinstall the app under the same account, your data will be restored.
•   Customizable reports. Export your data to a tab-delimited text file.
•   Check your progress with stats: total, today’s, yesterday’s and monthly stats.
•   Plus other features, and more in development.
```

https://youtu.be/i6NTJ2MUCpU

Disclaimer: Answer provided by the app developer.